# Comment_Reply_Link Not Showing?

Tags: comments

When I use the following code, everything shows *except* the reply link!  Anybody know what I've done wrong?  I'd like the link to show up with the word 'Reply.'

Live example: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=1948#commentlist

In my header:

```
<?php
if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments') )
  wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
?>
```

In comments.php:

```
<?php if($comments) : ?>  
    <?php foreach($comments as $comment) : ?>  
        <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">  
            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>  
                <p>Your comment is awaiting approval</p>  
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php if(function_exists('get_avatar')) { echo get_avatar($comment, '60'); } ?>
<cite class="fn"><?php comment_author_link(); ?> on <?php comment_date(); ?> at <?php comment_time(); ?></cite>
<?php echo comment_reply_link(array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'])); ?>
            <?php comment_text(); ?>  

        </li>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>  
<?php else : ?>  
    <p>No comments yet</p>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where are `$depth` and `$args` coming from? :::. I cannot see that `max_depth` in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link)... ::::. The `echo` seems unnecessary to `comment_reply_link`.

Comment: To extend what @brasofilo said: either you're not showing your full code, or you've got undefined variables. What errors are generated if you set `WP_DEBUG` to true? Also: where do you define `$depth` and `$args`? And finally: **why are you using a hard-coded comment list rather than `wp_list_comments()`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be twofold:

1. Ensure you are properly enqueueing the `comment-reply` script
2. Replace your hard-coded comment list with [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)

### Enqueueing `comment-reply`

I would recommend hooking into `comment_form_before()`:

```
function wpse71451_enqueue_comment_reply() {
    if ( get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); 
    }
}
// Hook into comment_form_before
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'wpse71451_enqueue_comment_reply' );
```

### Outputting the comment list

Using `wp_list_comments()` with default output in your code:

```
<?php if($comments) : ?>  
    <ol class="commentlist">
        <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
    </ol>
<?php else : ?>  
    <p>No comments yet</p>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you need specific markup for the comment list, you can pass a callback as a parameter to `wp_list_comments()`. But I would strongly recommend making sure everything works with the default output *first*, and then try to customize.

You can use your own custom markup in a callback, but you'll need to be sure to define the variables you're using, such as `$depth` and `$args`. If you can provide specific markup questions, I can help construct the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply missing the comment reply script. Enqueue it and you're don.

```
// Add this to your bootstrap, which should be hooked to `after_setup_theme`
# Add Scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse71451_comment_scripts', 0 );
/**
 * Scripts
 * + Comment reply
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse71451_comment_scripts()
{
    # Comment reply script
    if ( 
        is_singular() 
        AND get_option( 'thread_comments' ) 
    )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, does this simply go in functions.php?  That is where I've added it and I'm still not getting a link :-S

Comment: This only works if you've "threaded comments" activated on your settings page.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working with threaded comments enabled.

Comment: Check if the script is enabled and get loaded (FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools). Hint: This is only for singular posts/pages (see the conditional comment).

Comment: Hmm... still can't figure it out.

Comment: What is "can't figure it out"? Any problems, errors? Does the script load? Mate, I need info if I shall be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, I updated the question with a live link and all of my relevant code.  I'm not a coding guy, I'm a design guy.  As far as I know, I believe the script loads and the word "Reply" just isn't showing up.

Comment: @siouxfan45 Can you explain me why you copied my answer into the question? Makes no sense... Also: You didn't even read the comment in the code. Please do this and wrap the action call properly. And yes, on single pages the comment reply script now is loaded. I can see it inside the dev tools.

Comment: To show users what I'm doing and the results, as that is now what is running on the site.  I don't quite understand the comment, I'm not a coding guy for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `wp_list_comment` with a custom callback, ie:

```
<?php wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'my_wp_list_comment')); ?>
```

Then make sure that you pass the right depth parameters when calling `comment_reply_link` inside that callback, just like this:

```
<?php
    function my_wp_list_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {

        // ...blah

        // The actual comment
        comment_text(); 

        // The comment reply link with the correct parameters
        comment_reply_link( array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args[ 'max_depth' ] )
            , $comment->comment_ID
            , $comment->comment_post_ID
        );
    }
?>
```